# MVC.NET 404 outside of Domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I am trying to get a demo site for a client setup.  This is the 1st application my company is doing in MVC.NET, so I get to experience all the new things to find out (and all the headaches it'll cause).

Anyway, the site works fine locally (localhost) and on the server inside our domain.  External users not on the domain however, only get 404 errors.  I've tried several different settings/ config options I've found on this site, but nothing is working.  I don't know if it's a web.config issue or an IIS issue, or even simply a permissions issue (though it has all the same permissions as the other sites we run with Web Forms).

IIS: v7 in intergrated mode.
Windows Server Web

Comment: I wonder if the problem has anything to do with MVC or IIS. I am leaning to think that the issue is IIS. Can those users with problems browse to a plain HTML file on the same location?

Comment: Negative.  that's what they're actually trying to browse to for our site mock.  I'm sure it's not an MVC issue, since I can see the pages.  It's most likely IIS, not configured correctly or permissions, but the permissions are the same for our normal asp.net sites, and they all work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the answers everyone.  Turns out it was something with our DNS routing setup with the sub-domains. It was getting rerouted to a place that didn't exist.  Our IT guy finally got around to fixing it (ugh!)

Answer (score 0):

Well, because you received a 404, the server is being reached okay which is a good sign. (Dealing with firewall issues at a company is always a lot of fun.)

A common problem for something like this is the use of virtual directories to host the website. For example, if the address to your site is http://example.com/MySite/, in MVC that would translate to: /MySite/View/Index.aspx. HOWEVER...if you are using virtual folders, /MySite/ may instead point to another spot on the server (e.g. C:\WebSites\MySite). If you are indeed using virtual paths, make sure you have your files stored at the correct path.

There is a troubleshooting tutorial here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248033

Comment: we have our environment setup to not use virtual directories.  our drive name is like this: z:\projects\projectName\www   we server our demo sites like this:  projectName.demo.companyName.com

Comment: I can browse to the URL projectName.demo.companyName.com from my work computer (everyone at work can), however, people outside of our domain get the 404.